# Shopify proxy application/liquid will only download response

Tags: php, laravel, shopify, liquid

For the shopify application proxy, you are supposed to set the response to Content-Type: application/liquid, as explained [here](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/display-data-on-an-online-store-with-an-application-proxy-app-extension).

I am using Laravel, but even trying a basic php example, the browser will only download the response, it will not display it.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/liquid');

echo "test";
```

Even just that will download a file with the contents "test".

I've tried .htaccess changes, and those do not work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a request to the endpoint, the proxy returns that desired content (Liquid or JSON or vanilla HTML). It is up to you to decide where to display it in DOM. Since you know where you want to display your response, you can use Javascript to pinpoint a DOM node to replace, and replace it.

The proxy pattern has no magic with the response that makes it suddenly visible. If the response has Liquid tags in it, Shopify will fill those in as best it can, meaning the big string of HTML you get back from the Proxy, is ready to be glued into DOM.

Comment: "It is up to you to decide where to display it in DOM"
- Not when you return a response with the application/liquid content type. "Shopify renders any Liquid code in the request body in the context of the shop using the shop's theme" as mentioned here: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/display-data-on-an-online-store-with-an-application-proxy-app-extension

There would be no javascript involved.

Comment: I think it's easier to look at it from the underlying issue, which is why I included a basic code example. When the content type is set to application/liquid, the browser downloads it. How can this be remedied? Because that's really the issue here, I believe.

Comment: Ok.. so response is rendered in content_for_layout when Liquid. Fine. So you expect to see test and you see nothing. What is the response in the console? Are you sure your header is set correctly?

Comment: It's not that I see nothing, it's that it downloads a file with the contents "test." Yes, the header is set; otherwise, it wouldn't download a file. It doesn't download application/json. It will only download when a custom header, such as "application/liquid," is set.